# How to reduce space gap between lines of a GridLayout?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I created a container which has a GridLayout as its layout manager. I set 10 lines and 2 columns for the grid. I want to reduce the space gap between the grid lines. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the margin of the components within the layout to 0.

Comment: Ok , I get the UnselectedStyle and SelectedStyle of each component within the layout , and I set their margin to 0,0,0,0.